# passing multiple props to component (context API)

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have two `<AuthConsumer>`,`<PeopleConsumer>` 
and It is belongs to HOC like this:

```js
    const withAuth = WrappedComponent => {
      return () => (
        <AuthConsumer>{props => { console.log(props); return <WrappedComponent auth={props} />}}</AuthConsumer>
      );
    };
```

Using like this is works I can get auth as a props.

`export default withAuth(withRouter(LoginPage));`

but, when I tired `export default withPeople(withAuth(withRouter(LoginPage)));` is not works I can't get auth, people as props.

So I looked up official document it says:
use like this to passing multiple props from contextAPI

```js
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {theme => (
        <UserContext.Consumer>
          {user => (
            <ProfilePage user={user} theme={theme} />
          )}
        </UserContext.Consumer>
      )}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
```

So I tried this, but looks ugly:

```js
const withTest = WrappedComponent => {
  return () => (
    <AuthConsumer>
      {auth => (
        <PeopleConsumer>
          {people => (
            <WrappedComponent auth={auth} people={people} />
          )}
        </PeopleConsumer>
      )}
    </AuthConsumer>
  )
}
```

**In my case is there are better way to providing multiple props?**

Please let me know if you need info.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    const withAuth = WrappedComponent => {
      return (props) => (
        <AuthConsumer>{auth => { console.log(props, auth); return <WrappedComponent {...props} auth={auth />}}</AuthConsumer>
      );
    };
```